# C# - Set Property of a Property with Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

SO Community,

So I'm learning C# and am still trying to wrap my head around reflection. In particular trying to use it to access a property of a property on a class.

I've boiled down the basic task that I'm trying to accomplish below:

```
public enum SIGNAL_STATE { NOT_RETRIEVED = 0, RETRIEVING = 1, RETRIEVED = 2, FAILED = 3 }

public class MyObjectClass
{
    public string MyString;
    private SIGNAL_STATE _state = SIGNAL_STATE.NOT_RETRIEVED;
    public SIGNAL_STATE State { get { return _state; } set { _state = value;} }
}

public class NeedToReflect
{
    private MyObjectClass _myObject1 = new MyObjectClass();
    private MyObjectClass _myObject2 = new MyObjectClass();
    private MyObjectClass _myObject3 = new MyObjectClass();

    public MyObjectClass MyObject1
    {
        get{return _myObject1;} 
        set{_myObject1 = value;}
    }

    public MyObjectClass MyObject2
    {
        get{return _myObject2;}
        set{_myObject2 = value;}
    }

    public MyObjectClass MyObject3
    {
        get{return _myObject3;}
        set{_myObject3 = value;}
    }

    public static void Main(string [] args){
        NeedToReflect needToReflect = new NeedToReflect();

        string fieldName;
        for(int idx = 1; idx<=3; ++idx)
        {
            fieldName = String.Format("MyObject{0}",idx);

            //TODO: set state of 'MyObject' values to SIGNAL_STATE.RETRIEVING

        }
    }
}
```

**edit 1**:

At *Yair Nevet's* suggestion I'm grabbing the FieldInfo from the applicable object like,

```
FieldInfo fieldInfo = needToReflect.GetType().GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

But from there I get hung up on accessing and setting the right 'State' Field/Property on that member field

**Solution** (ie. here's what I plugged in on that TODO comment):

```
// Determine what binding flags will give us proper access to our member field
BindingFlags bindFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance;
// Get the field for that field
FieldInfo fieldInfo = needToReflect.GetType().GetField(fieldName, bindFlags);
// Pass in the containing object that we're reflecting on to get an instance of the member field
MyObjectClass myField = (MyObjectClass) fieldInfo.GetValue(needToReflect);
// We can now directly access and edit the value in question
myField.State = SIGNAL_STATE.RETRIEVING;
```

That does it. Thanks to *Shlomi Borovitz* for pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: If you still learning C#, I would advise to dive into reflection later on... 

Remember that it's there, remember what it is used for - and leave it to when you control C#. And then remember, that it has many disadvantages - so think carefully before using it

Comment: This is a great suggestion... but alas, as so often happens I find myself supporting code where this particular design pattern is going to be essential.

Comment: Then I hope my answer helped you

Comment: BTW, this is not a design pattern... More like an anti-pattern, or... Necessary evil

Comment: @darkpbj +1 for updating your answer with the full solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FieldInfo` object which returned by `GetField` has property which called `FieldInfo`, which returns the type of that field.
And you can query it for that type's (the type of the field) properties/fields (and whatever you want) - and get/set them.

Remember that both `GetType` method (of any object), and the `FieldInfo.FieldType` property return `Type` object, that you can query in reflection.

```
object obj =... 
var field = obj.GetType().GetField(fieldName,...);
field.FieldType.GetField(... 
//etc... etc...
```

For each field, you can query the type and for each type, you can query the fields, and get/set them.

BTW, in C# 4.0 you can use the `dynamic` pseudo type (it used as a type when declaring dynamic variable, but it's not a real type), and then using that variable, while assuming which properties/fields/methods that variable would have in runtime (ie, using them like they are known in compile time although they don't). 
This will not work for private members (and I can't warn you enough against calling private members in reflection), but for public members, this would make your code simple and readable, like you never used reflection (although, behind the scenes [in this case] reflection would be used).

Comment: Cool, this gets me even closer. So say I do a `FieldInfo stateFieldInfo = fieldInfo.FieldType.GetField("_state",...);` (with the `SetField` BindingFlag on) If I do `stateFieldInfo.SetValue(...)` I just can't figure out what to pass in for my first argument.

Comment: You need to get the value of the field, and pass that as the first variable (think about it - it's very logical)

Comment: And I've updated the answer. You might find the update very useful :-) (hopefully)

Comment: This is the right answer, it just took me a little while to figure out what the exact implementation would look like. Question is updated with my four lines of code. For the record, I wouldn't go so far as to call this an anti-pattern. If anything I think it has a certain folksy-charm, almost bordering on elegance. I guess I could go on debating best practices, but that's another topic for another time. Anyways, Thanks!

Comment: To be precise, it's an anti-pattern in certain cases. In the others, it's just necessary evil :)      

I'm saying that after seeing, and correcting code which used reflection to simulate polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a **Property** while the member is actually a private **Field**:

```
propertyName = String.Format("MyObject{0}",idx);
```

Use `GetField` method instead for that:

```
needToReflect.GetType().GetField(propertyName, BindingFlags.NonPublic |BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: Interesting, this might be my magic bullet. I'm plugging this into my stripped down example app now to see what I can do with it

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. This is very close. Say that I have the `FieldInfo` returned from your suggestion. Then, to set the property of that field (or should it be field of the field?) how do I find the instance of the object I need to set. ie: `fieldInfo.FieldType.GetProperty("State").SetValue( ##Missing this instance## ,SIGNAL_STATE.RETRIEVING,null);`

Answer (score 0):

Go through these steps...

`1) Get the Type.`
`2) Have an instance of that type.`
`3) Get the PropertyInfo for the property.`
`4) Call "GetSetMethod" on the PropertyInfo object.  It will return a MethodInfo object.`
`5) Invoke the MethodInfo object using the instance of the type and a value.`

Comment: No need to call GetMethod/SetMethod. 
There are GetValue/SetValue methods on the PropertyInfo object, which you can call directly.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
class ClassyMcClass
{
    public int PropertyB { get; set; }
}

class MyClass
{
    public ClassyMcClass PropertyA { get; set; }
}
```

The following code uses reflection on a `MyClass` object to set the int value of `PropertyB` in `PropertyA` to `NewValue`:

```
PropertyInfo propA = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("PropertyA");
PropertyInfo probBofA = propA.PropertyType.GetProperty("PropertyB");

// Set property B of property A, where obj is of type MyClass
probBofA.SetValue(propA.GetValue(obj), NewValue, null);
```